# 2 Form Submits interfering with each other

Tags: php, html, forms

I have a `PHP` script where I upload a `*.txt` file and I use the information inside that `*.txt` file to do some things.

**The form for uploading this text file:**

```
<form method="post" action="index.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">

     <input class="file-choice" name="file" type="file" />

     <input class="upload-button" type="submit" value="Upload Bestand" name="start" />

</form>
```

After I worked with this file I want to give the visitor a choice to change some things, with their own input.

**The form for the user input:**

```
<form  method="post">

    <div class="input-block">

    <b>Rechts naar links:</b> <br>
    <input type="radio" name="horizontaal" value="rl-aan">Aan
    <input type="radio" name="horizontaal" value="rl-uit">Uit<br>

    </div>

    <div class="input-block">

    <b>Verticaal:</b> <br>
    <input type="radio" name="verticaal" value="ver-aan">Aan
    <input type="radio" name="verticaal" value="ver-uit">Uit<br>

    </div>

    <div class="input-block">

    <b>Diagonaal:</b> <br>
    <input type="radio" name="diagonaal" value="dia-aan">Aan
    <input type="radio" name="diagonaal" value="dia-uit">Uit<br>

    </div>

        <input type="submit" name="test" />

</form>
```

My problem is when I press the submit button of either the file upload or user input the other form is retested. So for example if I press the submit for the user input, the file that I uploaded before is gone.

I tried changing the method from `POST` to `GET` and I've tried to give both the submits the same name but both did not work.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Use AJAX to send the data

Comment: @Johan Did you check the filename of the file you are uploading? If the same file is uploaded. it will override the previously uploaded file.

Comment: John Reca, I don't upload a new file. I just ask some user input with radio buttons. So I don't think that is the problemm.

Comment: @Matt It is a school project where we are only allowed to use PHP / HTML

Comment: To what php file does your second form post to? assuming both forms are posting to the same index.php?

Comment: And how does you PHP code look like?

Comment: @Yoram de Langen Thanks but I already fixed it :)

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

I had to work with sesions to save the needed variables from reading the file and add the name of the user input submit to all the scripts except the read script from the file.

Answer (score -1):

Give different form id and submit button id .

Comment: Giving them all an uniqe id did not help. But thanks for the input.

Comment: Hi @PJ, I think you have enough reputation to give suggestion in comment box.